# Redirect based on the beginning of the path

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a Laravel project. The project itself has a "legacy" version with a whole different structure. It's logged that some users are trying to access a file that is not found in the new environment.

For a quick "fix", we want to redirect paths like

- `/media/22044/blablabla.pdf` to `/en/press`

The quick solution is to use

```
Redirect 301 /media/22044/blabla.pdf /en/press
```

But we want the path behind `/media/` to be dynamic.
I'm new with `.htaccess` stuff.
Is there a way to do it?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# this one works, but not dynamic
#Redirect 301 /media/2336/blabla.pdf /en/press

# failed experiments
#Redirect 301 (\/media)(.*)$ /en/press
#Redirect 301 ^/media/(.*)$ /en/press
#RewriteRule ^/media/(.*) /en/press [R=301,NC,L]
Redirect 301 /media/(.*) /en/press
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive (not `Redirect`) *before* your existing rewrite.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect "/media/<anything>" to "/en/press"
RewriteRule ^media/ /en/press [R=301,L]

# Rewrite all requests to the "/public" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

The `Redirect` directive uses simple prefix-matching, not a regex. But is also processed later in the request.

And note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, unlike the `Redirect` directive.

Comment: Ah okay, so I had to put the rule before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public`. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: @AldoAdhi Yes, the order of the mod_rewrite directives is important. If you place it after the _rewrite_ then it's simply never processed. Note that `Redirect` (mod_alias) belongs to a different module and is still processed _after_ mod_rewrite. You should not mix rewrites/redirects from both modules as you can get unexpected conflicts.

Comment: @AldoAdhi I assume you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rule file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1 [L,NC]

###new redirect here...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.*/media/22044/blablabla\.pdf\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /en/press? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en/press)/?$ media/22044/blablabla\.pdf [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. 
Are you sure with {THE_REQUEST}?

I also tried with {REQUEST_URI} but still doesn't work.

Also why is it media/22044/blablabla\.pdf not media/22044/blablabla.pdf?

Comment: @AldoAdhi, ok so what you getting when you have posted my rules?

Comment: It still redirects to 404 page.

Comment: So basically what I need is:

`http://<domain>/media/12345/blablabla.pdf` redirect to `http://<domain>/en/press`

Comment: @AldoAdhi, ok sure, I have edited my answer, please make sure to keep your .htaccess file along with your media folder and then try it out.

Comment: Oh, I think there's a misunderstanding. What I need is the path behind after `/media/` is dynamic.

So like,
/media/12345/blabla.pdf 
/media/46777/testing.pdf
/media/lorem/ipsum.pdf
etc...
the thing is the path behind /media/ is dynamic

can redirect to
/en/press

Is that possible?

Comment: @AldoAdhi, ohhhh that's not possible without keeping values into the URL. Can you keep your URL like eg: `http://localhost:80/en/press/media/blabla/blabla/bla` etc? Where `blabla/blabla/bla` can change in backend to .pdf file.

Comment: Ah I see, thought that was possible. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @AldoAdhi, do you want to do it? I could write for you then, if you ok with it.

Comment: I think we're good now. If it's not possible to redirect from /media/<dynamic paths> to /en/press, I'll try another approach (not using htaccess), because it's not really wise to put all possible paths (there's a lot) into htaccess.